Constrained Bipartite Matching
Let $G = (X,Y,E)$ be a bipartite graph. For some $A \subseteq X$ we say that $A$ can be perfectly matched if there is a matching $M \subseteq E$ such that all vertices in $A$ are matched; that is, for every $a \in A$ there is $e \in M$ such that $a$ is an endpoint of $e$. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be all subsets $A \subseteq X$ that can be perfectly matched. We can decide in polynomial time if some $A \subseteq X$ belongs to $\mathcal{M}$ using maximum matching (while removing the vertices $X \setminus A$ from the graph).
In addition, let $\Pi \subseteq 2^X$ be some downward monotone constraint satisfying that there is a polynomial time algorithm that given $B \subseteq X$ decides if $B \in \Pi$. The above constraints $\mathcal{M}$ and $\Pi$ are decidable in polynomial time; however, I wonder if we can decide if a partition of $X$ into a set in $\mathcal{M}$ and a set in $\Pi$ can be NP-Hard. Namely,
Question: Are there examples for $\Pi$ such that it is NP-Hard to find a partition $A,B$ of $X$ such that $A \in \mathcal{M}$ and $B \in \Pi$?

By using the bipartite graph, we can encode a constraint saying $|A| \le k$, for a number $k$. Therefore, an example of an NP-hard case is if we have another graph $H$ with the vertex set $X$, and $\Pi$ is the family of independent sets of $H$. In particular, this encodes the maximum independent set problem.

I am not sure this is good enough: the independent set problem is NP-Hard and we want $\Pi$ to be solvable in polynomial time.

Deciding whether a vertex set is an independent set is not NP-hard though. So $B \in \Pi$ can be decided in polynomial time.

This problem captures the maximum independent set problem, which is NP-hard, as follows.
Suppose we wish to decide if a graph $H = (V_H, E_H)$ has an independent set of size $\ge k$.
We construct $G = (X,Y,E)$ so that $X = V_H$, $Y$ is a set of size $|V_H|-k$, and $E$ contains all possible edges between $X$ and $Y$. Now for $A \subseteq X$, we have $A \in \mathcal{M} \Leftrightarrow |A| \le |V_H|-k$.
We let $\Pi$ consist of all subsets of $V_H$ that are independent sets in $H$. The set $\Pi$ is downwards-closed, and whether $B \in \Pi$ can clearly be decided in polynomial time.
Now there exists a partition $A,B$ of $X$ so that $A \in \mathcal{M}$ and $B \in \Pi$ if and only if $H$ has an independent set of size $\ge k$.
